# Java, Passing objects from one arraylist to another

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I have a class with two ArrayLists that store two different types of objects

I have another class - SortedArrayList - which is responsible for sorting the above arraylists alphabetically and printing them to the console or to the file

I was wondering if there is any way for the SortedArrayList to acquire the added objects from the previous ArrayLists without adding them again to the SortedArrayList?

Please point me in the right direction

Thank you

Comment: Are you implementing Comparable in the classes that comprise the two ArrayLists of the first class you mention?

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! Yes, I do implement Comparable in both of the classes

Comment: I find your question unclear - can you provide some code or pseudo-code to help illustrate what you want to achieve? If you could also describe the reason why you want to do this that might help as well.

Answer (score 0):

If the objects are similar, you can use an interface so that the SortedArrayList can work with that and then will be able to work with both Objects.